# How to set the javascript function for print into landscape?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, printing

I was trying to set the print orientation into landscape through javascript. I'm only just using the window.print() function for the page's content to be printed.
here's the code:

```
<a href="" onClick="window.print();return false">
<img src="images/print.png"></a>
```

With this I was able to print a sample page. But only it was on portrait format. The client requires it to be in landscape. so I tried on many codes I found. here's the one am sure your most familiar with.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#printLandscape").on('click',function () {
$('head').append('<link href="printLandscape.css" title="printLandscape" rel="stylesheet" />');
});
</script>
```

since it wasn't a button that am using to call the print function but an image type with href, I tried to change the previous one with:

```
<a href="" onClick="window.print();return false" id="printLandscape">
<img src="images/print.png"></a>
```

See the id="printLandscape", I tried that on to be able to call the javascript function declared above and make the page print into my desired format which is landscape. But when I tried to print, to see if it was working. The printed page still has the default/formal or portrait type.

Is there something am missing? Or did I not declare the javascript properly especially the id on href for it not to work fine?

S.O.S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should make the page property landscape in CSS:

```
@media print{@page {size: landscape}}
```

The support is left to the browser and it appears not to be supported in all browsers.

Comment: but seems that it does not works anymore

Comment: This is not working in angular with chrome v78.0.3904.108 (64-bit)